# Pandas with py2exe: ImportError: C extension: dist not built

Tags: python, pandas, py2exe, setuptools

Trying to build a py2exe (0.6.9) package, the module has a dependency that uses pandas (0.16.2).

When "py2exe'ing", no errors are shown and the pandas python package is within the py2exe package.

When trying to run the .exe, it fails with:

> File "pandas__init__.pyo", line 13, in
>
> ImportError: C extension: dist not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C extensions first.

I tried building pandas with that suggested command option, and then built a wheel from it, but didn't change the result.

What else could I be missing?

Comment: it turns out the error is a bit before than that, since the wheel was created in a virtualenv, py2exe with virtualenv has an issue with distutils. The error log started with : "UserWarning: The
virtualenv distutils package at %s appears to be in the same location as the sys
tem distutils?"

Comment: What version of Python are you using? I get this same issue with Anaconda 2.5.0 (Python 2.7.11, 32-bit). It seems that py2exe does not like pre-compiled libraries, such as the ones that come with Anaconda. Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: Hi, it happened with Python 2.7.5, 32-bit. We couldn't solve it, so we searched for another tool and switched to PyInstaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: This is not a fix to the problem, but if for anyone is also possible, I can confirm that changing to [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) was a workaround.